# Installing Sitecore 9.2 with Sitecore Install Assistant shows error - Identity Server Installation Step

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-assistant

Sitecore XP 9.2.0 installation fails with the error.
[image]

Sitecore Install Assistant suggests checking the log. The log file contains the following entries:

```
                      ************************************
                           Sitecore Install Framework
                                 Version - 2.1.0
                      ************************************


WorkingDirectory       : C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\Sitecore\Sitecore 9.2.0 rev. 002893 (Setup XP0 Developer 
                         Workstation rev. r150)
WhatIf                 : False
Verbose                : SilentlyContinue
Configuration          : C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\Sitecore\Sitecore 9.2.0 rev. 002893 (Setup XP0 Developer 
                         Workstation rev. r150)\XP0-SingleDeveloper.json
Debug                  : SilentlyContinue
AutoRegisterExtensions : False
WarningAction          : Continue
ErrorAction            : Stop
InformationAction      : Continue





[------------------- GeneratePasswords : SetVariable -------------------------]

[ IdentityServerCertificates_CreatePaths : EnsurePath --------------------------]
[IdentityServerCertificates_CreatePaths]:[Create] C:\certificates

[ IdentityServerCertificates_Display... : WriteInformation --------------------]
Certificate Password: )QjbMu:>806^G#60XPmO

[ IdentityServerCertificates_CreateR... : NewRootCertificate ------------------]
Found multiple certificates, selecting certificate with longest expiry.
Exported certificate file C:\certificates\SitecoreRootCert.pfx

[ IdentityServerCertificates_CreateS... : NewSignedCertificate ----------------]
Found multiple certificates, selecting certificate with longest expiry.
Could not find Cert: sc-xp-920identityserver.dev.local in Cert:\LocalMachine\My
Exported certificate file C:\certificates\sc-xp-920identityserver.dev.local.pfx

[---------- IdentityServer_CreatePaths : EnsurePath --------------------------]
[IdentityServer_CreatePaths]:[Create] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc-xp-920identityserver.dev.local

[-------- IdentityServer_CreateAppPool : AppPool -----------------------------]
[IdentityServer_CreateAppPool]:[Create] sc-xp-920identityserver.dev.local
[IdentityServer_CreateAppPool]:[Setting] processModel.identityType => ApplicationPoolIdentity
[IdentityServer_CreateAppPool]:[Setting] managedRuntimeVersion => 
[IdentityServer_CreateAppPool]:[Setting] processModel.loadUserProfile => True
[IdentityServer_CreateAppPool]:[Setting] processModel.idleTimeoutAction => Suspend

[ IdentityServer_SetAppPoolCertStore... : FilePermissions ---------------------]
[IdentityServer_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Allow] IIS AppPool\sc-xp-920identityserver.dev.local
[IdentityServer_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Path] C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\5bbbe01bf59748c5204d66d57ec057b5_bf574485-a3b5-4063-83ca-fcdd6c376d2b
[IdentityServer_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Rights] Read
[IdentityServer_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Inherit] None
[IdentityServer_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Propagate] None

[-------- IdentityServer_CreateWebsite : Website -----------------------------]
[IdentityServer_CreateWebsite]:[Create] sc-xp-920identityserver.dev.local
[IdentityServer_CreateWebsite]:[Setting] applicationPool => sc-xp-920identityserver.dev.local
[IdentityServer_CreateWebsite]:[Setting] physicalPath => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc-xp-920identityserver.dev.local

[---------- IdentityServer_StopWebsite : ManageWebsite -----------------------]
[IdentityServer_StopWebsite]:[Stop] sc-xp-920identityserver.dev.local
The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
[TIME] 00:00:08
The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
```

Comment: seems it's crashing when stopping ID server? Did it actually create it?

Comment: First check if "sc-xp-920identityserver.dev.local" is setup as windows service and it is running. Then check if it is setup on the IIS and is running including AppPool. Also make sure that your IIS is running.

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it by starting the "Windows Process Activation Service" and the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced this while installing `Sitecore 10 with SIA`. I know it's been asked way back and it would have been resolved.
However to help other community members who could face this in the future. follow the below steps to fix it.

1. Open IIS and check if your application pool for the identity server is up and running.

   [image]
2. Open `Services` and check if the below services are running. The application pool requires these services to be enabled before starting.

   - Windows Process Activation Service — WAS
   - World Wide Web Publishing Service — W3SVC
3. Start these services on `windows services (services.msc)` should solve the issue.

   [image]

Start a fresh install of Sitecore.

Hope it helps!